# Stopping a program in terminal that has been started from Python

Tags: python, shell, system

I have a python script that starts another program from system (the shell script actually calls the program itself, the tag-bm.sh):

```
def tag(obt_path, corpora_path):
    print corpora_path
    os.system('cd ' + obt_path + ' && ./tag-bm.sh ' + corpora_path + ' > ' + corpora_path + '.obt')
    os.system('pwd')
```

Sometimes this program goes into an infinite loop, which creates a problem for my main program. Is there a way to set things up so that if the program has not ended within a set time python disrupts it?

Comment: Does `tag-bm.sh` go into infinite loop?

Comment: maybe start it in the background  and use subprocess with .kill

Comment: No, not the shell script itself, but another program that the script calls...

Comment: do a `ps aux` in the terminal and see if either your python script, `tag-bm.sh` or any other scripts it calls show up in the output

Comment: @ArashSaidi,  you can still kill by pid

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ok, how would I do that?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget the list is so long, impossible to find which process is started from the script. But the script actually just calls one program to start, it's a parser, the script just gives it loads of arguments...

Comment: when you run the code what does tag-bm.sh show as in `top` output?

Comment: no, the tab-bm.sh does not show up.

Comment: So let's say `myscript.py` calls `tag-bm.sh`, which in turn calls `somescript.sh`. Do `ps aux | grep myscript`, `ps aux | grep tag\-bm`, `ps aux | grep somescript`. See which one is running (you'll also see its PID). Kill the PID

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Oh, ok, how can that happen automatically from python. The program I'm writing calls the parser thousands of times, and then it has to kill those that do not finish within 24 hours.

Comment: Personally, I'd start by looking into `multiprocessing`, though I haven't really tried sto solve this specific problem with it

Answer (score 2):

Find out the name of the command, for instance if it's `cp` then you can get the pid of the command using either `pgrep cp` or `pidof cp`. Note that this will return the pids of all `cp` processes. Call the `pgrep` right after you started the command and it should be on top so the pid in that case is `pgrep cp | head -n1` or `pidof cp | cut -s -f1`. Store this variable and kill it later at a desired time.

Alternatively you could run the command with `timeout` you can add a value after which the command will automatically receive a kill signal. Example usage: `timeout 500s cp large_file destination_file`. The cp will get killed after 500 seconds in this case. `man timeout´ for more information.

Comment: Thanks, will look into this tomorrow! Great fun!

Comment: My pleasure, just remember to accept if it suited your needs :)